# Get the 2 digit year in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to get the current 2 digit year and increment by one. So the current number I'm looking for should be 11. How?

Comment: What result do you want in 2099? ;)

Comment: I want to be retired and not care :)

Comment: The title of this question should be "get the 2 digit year +1" :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do `( YEAR( GETDATE() ) % 100 ) + 1`

See [GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) & [YEAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)

Comment: and do the `+ 1` before the `% 100`, if you want `xx99` to yield 0 rather than 100

Answer (score 34):

This will work for you

```
select Right(Year(getDate())+ 1,2)
```

Answer (score 16):

For SQL Server 2012 and above, I'd suggest using [`FORMAT(@DATE, 'yy')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(year, 1, GETDATE()), 'yy')
```

`Format` offers a cleaner, more readable solution. Thus, less guesswork, and a better maintainability.

Comment: @VeryColdAir The original question was ` get the current 2-digit year and increment by one`.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1),2) as YEAR
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this in sql server

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yy')
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question of getting the current year + 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always going to be using GetDate() why not just do something like this:

```
Select (Year(GetDate()) - 2000) + 1
```

Dang people. Always making things so complicated. It's not like you are going to be living for another 1000 years!

Answer (score -2):

```
select CAST( DAY(GETDATE()) as varchar(10))+'/'+CAST( month(GETDATE()) as varchar(10))+'/' +cast(right(year(getDate()),2) as varchar)
```