# Is there a simpler method for getting the two digit year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

EDIT: Forced to use 2008 R2

I need to get the two digit year to appended to an invoice number (for simplicity sake I am using a test variable). Previously I only needed the month and day appended but the customer is now asking for the two digit year.

**My Method:** REPLACE + SUBSTRING + STR + YEAR(variable DATETIME)

```sql
REPLACE((SUBSTRING(STR (Year(@Date),4),3,2)), ' ', '0')**
```

**My code:**

```
DECLARE @TestVariable AS VARCHAR(100),
@Date as datetime = GetDate()
SET @TestVariable = '1234' 
+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(@Date), 2), ' ', '0') 
+ REPLACE(STR(DAY(@Date), 2), ' ', '0') 
+  REPLACE((SUBSTRING(STR (Year(@Date),4),3,2)), ' ', '0')

PRINT @TestVariable
```

Comment: Since sargability is already out the window you could use `FORMAT`. Something like this. SET @TestVariable = '1234' + FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMddyy')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the 2 digit year in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708084/get-the-2-digit-year-in-t-sql)

Comment: Honestly, why would you *want* a 2-digit year in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu I can only assume they weren't around for the "fun" we had 25 years ago trying to unravel all the  2 digit years.

Comment: @Larnu because that is the requirement I was given. It's not my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, just *don't* work with 2 digit years any more; learn the lessons of last century's mistake and use 4 digits.

If you "have" to, then you could use `CONVERT` with a style code, and then just replace the characters with an empty string:

```sql
DECLARE @TestVariable varchar(100) = '1234',
        @Date datetime = GETDATE();

SELECT @TestVariable + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),@Date, 1),'/','');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the whole process, not just the year portion. Using FORMAT you can accomplish this easily.

```
DECLARE @TestVariable AS VARCHAR(100) = '1234' 
    , @Date as datetime = GetDate()

Select @TestVariable + FORMAT(@Date, 'MMddyy')
```

Comment: This solution would work if FORMAT was valid in 2008 R2.  But it isn't unfortunately I am working crippled

Comment: @Chrisl007  It is *assumed* that when asking a question you are using a supported version of the software, unless you advise otherwise. If you don't let us know the version, it's also assumed you are likely using the *latest* version (in this case SQL Server 2019). SQL Server 2008R2 has been **completely** unsupported for 3 years. If you *are* using unsupported technology, you need to let people know that in the question first so that you don't get answers that don't work in your environment.

Comment: Crippled indeed. I guess you are stuck using antiquated software so you will have to resort to antiquated techniques. Hope you have an upgrade plan in your future.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select replace(convert(varchar(20),@date,1)'/','') --or any other you need
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Style 1 is `MM/dd/yy`. This would *include* the `/` characters.

Comment: this solution almost works I had to use Larnu's method to remove the slashes

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo others' sentiment of "do you *really* have to use a two-digit year"? But if you have to, I like this sort of thing

```sql
set @TestVariable = '1234'
    + right('0' + cast(month(@date)      as varchar(2)), 2)
    + right('0' + cast(day(@date)        as varchar(2)), 2)
    + right('0' + cast(year(@date) % 100 as varchar(2)), 2);
```

To talk through the general approach, I'm using `right('0', «something», 2)` as a means to zero pad to two places, using `cast(«something» as varchar(2))` to get a string instead of a number (so implicit conversion doesn't just add zero and the relevant datepart), and finally `year(@date) % 100` to get the last two digits of the date.